# How to deploy node server to Vercel?

Tags: vercel

I have a simple node application with the following directory structure:

```
node_modules/
src/
  app.js
  api/
package.json
vercel.json
```

The starting point is `src/app.js` and `yarn start` is called to run the app.

After deploying, opening up the home route should return just the text `OK`, but instead I'm getting 404 not found.

What am I doing wrong?

**vercel.json**

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "src/app.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "src/app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```